# Passing Multiple Params - Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Newb RoR developer here.

I have a model called `size.rb` that basically has a variety of size elements.

Now, in my subsequent view, I have multiple sets of `radio_button_tags`. Since each set is independent, I renamed the each (`shirtsize_ids`, `waistsize_ids`, etc)

Now, the issue I'm having is how to pass all of these different `size_id` parameters to the controller. At the end of the day, they are all recorded as a `size_id` attribute in a joint-model called usersize, but since I had to differentiate them in the view (for radio button purposes), I'm stuck!

Thanks for the help

**view**

```
<% Size.select { |size| size.category == 'waist' }.sort.each do |size| %>
<%= radio_button_tag 'waistsize_ids[]', size.id, false, :id => "waistsizing-#{size.id}" %>
<% Size.select { |size| size.category == 'waist' }.sort.each do |size| %>
<%= radio_button_tag 'inseamsize_ids[]', size.id, false, :id => "inseamsizing-#{size.id}" %>
```

**controller**

```
def create
  @user_size = UserSize.new(params[:user_size])    
  params = {"waistsize" => {'id' => 'size.id'}}
  params.each do |size|

  UserSize.create(:size_id => size.id, :user_id => current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`radio_button` versus `radio_button_tag` might be a better choice:

```
<%= radio_button :waistsize, :id, size.id, :checked => false, :id => "waistsizing-#{size.id}" %>
<%= radio_button :inseamsize, :id, size.id, :checked => false, :id => "inseamsizing-#{size.id}" %>

# => params = { ..., "waistsize"=>{"id"=>"xyz"}, "inseamsize"=>{"id"=>"xyz"} }
```

Then, in the controller:

```
def create
  @user_size = UserSize.new(params[:user_size])    
  UserSize.create(:size_id => params[:waistsize][:id], :user_id => current_user.id)
  UserSize.create(:size_id => params[:inseamsize][:id], :user_id => current_user.id)
end
```

Comment: not sure if I understand the purpose here of changing to just radio_button - can I just specify the parameters in the controller as such?

Comment: I don't think you have stated the problem clearly.  What is wrong with the controller code above?  How does it fail?

Comment: Yep, sorry. The problem with the (updated) controller above - the one I posted, is that I get an undefined method `id' for ["waistsize", {"id"=>"size.id"}]:Array` error. Here's the reworded problem. I am trying to pass `size.id` parameters to the controller. Unfortunately, due to the nature of the radio button sets, I renamed the `ids` in the views - so I need to change the `params` in the controller. Make sense?

Comment: Still not sure if I understand the issue, and not sure why you redefine params with a string `{"id" => "size.id"}` in the `id` field at all.  But I guessed and edited anyway.

Comment: You are da best! Works perfectly for me. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

does the UserSize model habe something like a 'size_type', or why do u have 'waistsize' and 'inseamsize' etc..

Comment: plz ask your question in comments, thaNKS

Comment: thanks for the response - I do have a 'size_category" in my size model, but I have the "waistsize" 'inseamsize' here because I need to differentiate the radio button sets